# Installer doesn't display partition I want to install to

Tags: 10.10, installation, partitioning

While performing a Ubuntu 10.10 installation on my laptop, it doesn't show partitions pertaining to the PC.

My PC configuration is as follows :

- HP Pavilion dv6 - 2020AX
- AMD Turion II Dual Core Mobile Processor M500
- 4 GB RAM
- OS Installed : Windows 7
- 500 GB Hard drive partitioned as follows :

  - C : 227 GB (Free : 142 GB)
  - D : 11.9 GB (Free : 1.98 GB) - Recovery
  - F : 174 GB (Free : 18 GB)
  - G : 50.5 GB (Free : 50.4 GB)

So, I want to perform a Dual-boot installation on my PC, so that Ubuntu resides in the free disk space G:. 
Therefore, I started the Ubuntu 10.10 installation and select the manual partitioning feature in the installation.

However, in the 'Allocate Drive Space' section of the installation, following partitions information is displayed:

- Partition        Type                     Size                 Used
- /dev/sda

  - /dev/sda1           1 MB     unknown
  - /dev/sda2        ntfs                      208 MB                 unknown
  - /dev/sda3         ntfs                      244813 MB              168540 MB
  - /dev/sda4        ntfs                      255083 MB              3221 MB

where /dev/sda  - 500 GB

So, what exactly is the problem?
What is it should I do to install Ubuntu 10.10 in the G: disk space?
Why are the partitions not being shown as the way they should be?

Any Suggestions.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Will you be solving it with programming?

Comment: Question does not make sense.  First you say that it does not show any partitions, and then you list the partitions that it shows.

Comment: I guess the question was about a partition sized 50Gbyte which can be seen in Windows, but no partition is shown by ubuntu installer which can be that one.

Answer (score 2):

I have often seen this after an installation of windows what has happened,for technical reasons,is windows C partition has been placed 1Mb in. normally this would not matter except in this case linux knows you can only have four partitions and that is what it shows.
Solution delete the 1 MB partition grow C to fill it write to disk and reboot.

Comment: I don't think that linux knows only 4 partitions. If you talk about primary ones, then yes, but isn't it the same case with windows? Or does windows use some different partitioning method? Anyway, you can have more partitions with extended ones of course. But it's handled by linux too, so this sounds surprising for me.

Comment: I suspect windows doesn't see the 1MB partition as the questioner did not say it was there until he used linux and yes it was an assumption of mine that the were all primary partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems all of your hard drive is allocated for (if you add all the space it becomes about 500 GB) mainly in sda3 and sda4. I would imagine the partition is actually different than you think it is, I had windows completely overwrite my hard drive once even though I asked to save the existing partitions!

Be sure to check what is in 3 and 4, maybe use the built in windows disk management to reference. The other option is to use a Ubuntu Live disk and boot into a Linux OS to snoop around.

Be sure to backup!!!